# wordpress custom post editor in php

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, custom-post-type

I have a custom post and I would like to have a custom editor for it.

I know how to strip `tinyMCE` with the `add_filter('mce_buttons', 'clean_tinyMCE');`and I know how to remove the rest of elements either by `remove_meta_box('somediv', 'mpt', 'normal')` or by `$args['supports'] = array('title', 'editor');` for my custom post.

What I am looking for is a way **add some desired elements and functionality** via the wordpress api. Something resembling the following would be perfect:

```
add_filter('wp_default_editor', 'use_mine');

function use_mine(){
    return 'my_editor.php'; // In a perfect world..
}
```

or even something like this but without creating a duplicate:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'use_mine');

function use_mine(){
    add_menu_page('Name', 'name', 'manage_options', 'slug', 'my_editor.php', 'menu.svg'); // In a distant galaxy..
}
```

Is there a way to achieve that with php or do I **have to** use javascript?

Comment: you're probably looking for the [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function

Comment: @andrew This could actually work with some tweaking.. and I would also accept it as an answer, if you make it into one.

Comment: Its all good, hope it works out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

By Using

`add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, $context, $priority, $callback_args );`

Create Custom Textarea Field for Custom Post Type

Snippet Here...

http://wpshed.com/create-custom-meta-box-easy-way/